# Categorise multiple rows into one variable

Tags: r, categories

A simple question, but apparently not answered in StO yet.

I've got a long data frame where 3 of the columns are:

```
person | trip |  driver
=======================
1       car 
1       bike
1       train
1       walk
2       walk
2       train
2       boat
```

What I'd like is to populate column 'driver', so that it reads 1 if *at least* one of the trips is made by car, 0 otherwise:

```
person | driver
================
1       1 
1       1
1       1
1       1
2       0
2       0
2       0
```

I have a slight preference for doing this without recurring to fancy packages, but I am happy with most of the popular ones (e.g. plyr, data.table,sqldf....), or even new ones that prove helpful in the long term.

Thanks in advance,       .p.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use `data.table`, convert 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), we check whether there is `any` 'car' in the 'trip' grouped by 'person', convert the logical output to numeric (`+0L` or wrapping with `as.numeric`) and assign (`:=`) to 'driver' column.  If needed, we can remove the 'trip' column by assigning it to `NULL` or subset by `[, c(1,3), with=FALSE]`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, driver := any(trip == 'car')+0L, by = person][, trip := NULL]
```

Or instead of `any`, we can use `max(trip=='car')` as @Arun mentioned in the comments

```
setDT(df1)[, driver := max(trip == 'car'), by = person]
```

---

Or using a similar logic as above, we `group_by` 'person' and create a new column with `mutate` and remove the unwanted columns with `select`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(person) %>% 
   mutate(driver= any(trip=='car')+0L) %>%
   select(-trip)
```

---

Or with `base R`, we can use `ave` to create 'driver' and then `subset` to remove the 'trip' column.

```
df1$driver <- with(df1, ave(trip=='car', person, FUN=any)+0L)
subset(df1, select=-trip)
```

Comment: @Arun Thanks for the comments.  That is more compact

Comment: Thanks, this proves how much can be done with the 'with' and setDT !

Comment: Just to add I tried the setDT approach (setDT(df)[,driver:=max(trip),by=person], getting the error: 


Type of RHS ('integer') must match LHS ('double')

so I assume this is because one of my fields (driver) is integer, whereas the other (trip) is defined as double? Any quick way to reassign the type in the command itself?   Thanks!

Comment: Answering myself, it seems just chaging the type of the field inside the command does work:
setDT(df)[,driver:=as.numeric(max(trip)),by=person

Comment: @user3310782 If the column class don't match, we have to first change it before assigning.